# Growing Tomato Indoors from Cutting: When should I transplant to larger pot? When should I start seeing flowers?

Tags: indoors, tomatoes, transplanting, cuttings

I took a small cutting from an indeterminate tomato plant from an outdoor plant at the end of the growing season.  Cutting is getting pretty tall (about 19 inches).
Not sure what to do with it at this point to encourage strong roots and to get it to actually produce indoors over the winter.
The pot it is in is approximately 9 inches tall with an inside diameter of 7 inches.

1. should I get it to a bigger pot now?
2. should I add more light? - the light you see is a basic full spectrum, and there is morning sun coming from a window on the other side.
3. should I do any pruning at this point?
4. when might I expect to see flowers?

[image: Potted tomato plant]

Answer (score 1):

Tomatoes need a whole lot of light, for mid-summer-length daily durations.  That your plant wasn’t getting optimal amounts of light is suggested by its slightly leggy growth, and the interior light being a couple feet away.  Light strength diminishes by the square of the distance.

So yes, add more light, closer.  But it will be difficult to provide truly enough light.  I don’t think the plant needs a bigger pot, though that wouldn’t hurt.  I wouldn’t prune, as the shape isn’t a problem.  Or maybe pinch off the leader since once it gets much taller it’s hard to get it directly under grow lights.  If this is a cherry, which matures earlier than larger tomatoes, you might get a couple flowers.  Except for that, I’m not optimistic about the plant producing much fruit.  I’d love to be wrong about that - and to know actually happened with this plant.